# Batch for loop, Appending to text file, error, Reg Query, Win XP vs Win 7

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, text, registry, echo

Problem and Current Output: `%file3%` (%~dp0%computername%-programs_unsorted.txt) is not created on a computer with Win XP x86. However `%file3%` is created on one with Win 7 x86.

Need %file3% created with the below output (for example):

```
Adobe AIR 
Adobe AIR 
Adobe Flash Player 13 ActiveX 
Adobe Reader XI (11.0.07) 
Adobe Shockwave Player 12.1 
Cisco AnyConnect Network Access Manager 
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client  
Cisco Jabber Video for TelePresence 
Citrix Authentication Manager
```

Batch code:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "Version_tool=v39"

SET "file3=%~dp0%computername%-programs_unsorted.txt"
If Exist %file3% Del %file3%

Rem -------- Win XP x86 commands ---------
:WinXPx86
echo Win XP x86...
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (
'REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S ^| find "DisplayName"'
) do echo %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E>> %file3%
pause

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (
'REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S ^| find "QuietDisplayName"'
) do echo %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E>> %file3%
echo %computername%-programs_unsorted.txt created ...
pause
goto Continue
```

Answer (score 0):

This batch snippet doesn't work as described on either XP or Win7. I set a value for `%file3%` so I could run this on my systems.

`%file3%` never gets written for me on either version of Windows as long as delims is blank ("delims="). If I stick a space after the equals sign ("delims= "), I start getting output as follows.

On both Windows versions, I get a file that looks like this:

```
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Help Viewer 1.1 %B %C %D %E
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU %B %C %D %E
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) %B %C %D %E
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Intel(R) Network Connections Drivers %B %C %D %E
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 SP1 (x64) %B %C %D %E

    ...
```

%%A is holding the value of the complete line because "tokens=*" means that the whole line is a token. From the FOR command line help:

> If the last character in the tokens= string is an asterisk, then an
>   additional variable is allocated and receives the remaining text on
>   the line after the last token parsed.

So each whole line is stored in %%A and the other variables just get spit out as their own names.

To achieve the output you described, change your FOR commands. Add space as a delimiter and change the tokens you want. In XP, use "tokens=2,*" and in Win7 use "tokens=3,*". Here is the XP example that works:

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%A in (
'REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S ^| find "DisplayName"'
) do echo %%A %%B>> %file3%
```

When I make these changes, the program output looks like this in both XP and Win7:

```
Microsoft Help Viewer 1.1
Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
Intel(R) Network Connections Drivers
Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 SP1 (x64)
```

On XP, tons of Security Updates are listed. And "ParentDisplayName" is also being matched by your **find** filter on XP. Don't know if you want to amend that situation. It lists a lot of duplicates.

Comment: On Win XP in cmd, the command `REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S | find "DisplayName"` works, however %file3% does not get created with the results from your command with the batch code you gave. Please advise.

Comment: For me it works. I can't explain it, unless somehow you do not have a space after the equals sign in "delims=", or if file3 variable is not set. Your original sample code didn't set it, but I see that you've updated that, so I don't know.